# HTML CSS Two 2-column tables side by side with same height and width

Tags: html, css

I'm quering a MySQL database and use a script to put results into an automatically generated HTML-file.

I have two tables with 2 columns and 4 rows each that need to be put side-by-side.

I have put my html & css in fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/mika6891/7b0k049r/1/

My HTML code:

```
<!-- gene description -->
  <div id="container">
  <div id="gene_A_description" >GENE - A</div>
  <div id="gene_B_description" >GENE - B</div>
  </div>

 <div id="container">
  <table id="gene_A_text" class="listitems2">
      <tr>
          <td><b>test1</b></td>
          <td><!--test1-->test1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td><b>test2</b></td>
          <td><!--test2-->test2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td><b>test3</b></td>
          <td><!--test3-->test3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td><b>test4</b></td>
          <td><!--test4-->test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test</td>
      </tr>
      </table>

     <div id="container">
  <table id="gene_A_text" class="listitems2">
      <tr>
          <td><b>test1</b></td>
          <td><!--test1-->1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td><b>test2</b></td>
          <td><!--test2-->+</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td><b>test3</b></td>
          <td><!--test3-->test3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td><b>test4</b></td>
          <td><!--test4-->test test </td>
      </tr>
      </table>

  <div id="container">
  <div id="gene_A_description" >GENE - C</div>
  <div id="gene_B_description" >GENE - D</div>
  </div>
```

My CSS-code

```
table{
font-family:Arial;
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 10px;
}

#container{
width: 500px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

#gene_A_description{
width:200px;
height:50px;
background-color:#e13737;
color:white;
text-align:center;
margin-top: 30px;
float: left;
font-family: 'Arial Black', Gadget, sans-serif;
line-height: 50px;
}

#gene_B_description{
width:200px;
height:50px;
background-color:#e13737;
color:white;
text-align:center;
margin-top:30px;
float: right;
font-family: 'Arial Black', Gadget, sans-serif;
line-height: 50px;
 }

table.listitems2 {
width: 150px; 
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

 #gene_A_text{
float:left;
}

#gene_B_text{
float:right;
}
```

Now these html will be automatically generated so the table for GENE_A_TEXT and GENE_B_TEXT will never contain the same information and so will also not be of the same heigth, as can be seen in the example (because of test4 row).

I would want that the same rows in table GENE_A_TEXT and GENE_B_TEXT have the same height, depending on the amount of information that is in there. So that my next  GENE_C_DESCRIPTION and GENE_D_DESCRIPTION start at the same height, and not like it is now, that they are placed below GENE_B_TEXT

This is a picture of how it should look like

[image: this is how it should look like]

Comment: I didn't understand what you want. Can you please upload an image/illustration of your desired design? It'll be easer...

Comment: @TamarG off course, I'm sorry.

Comment: your title should be in same table , as currently they are separate.

Comment: I'm very confused as to why you  need 2 separate tables. I would recommend combining the tables into one which would solve your problem.

Comment: @jaunt yes, but how can I then make sure that they perfectly align on the screen, with one side (two first columns) floating left and one side (the last columns) floating right? And how do I handle the whith space in between then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so I have made a few assumptions to create this solution.

Firstly, I'm guessing that as you are setting the headers of the tables as `width:200px;` that the width of the two columns are 100px. (This can be changed if need be).

Secondly, these tables are not floated. This means you will not get desired behaviour with the rest of your content if that was desired. -Cannot be changed very easily.

And finally, you need the empty `<td></td>` 's in after the first table. I used this as a filler to get a floating effect. This cannot be changed without using a different approach.

```css
table{
  font-family:Arial;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 10px;
  width: 500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
thead th:nth-of-type(odd),tfoot th:nth-of-type(odd){
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:#e13737;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-family: 'Arial Black', Gadget, sans-serif;
  line-height: 50px;
}
td{width:100px;}
```

```html
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col><col><col><col><col>
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">GENE_A</th>
      <th colspan="1"></th>
      <th colspan="2">GENE_B</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">GENE_C</th>
      <th colspan="1"></th>
      <th colspan="2">GENE_D</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><b>test1</b></td>
      <td><!--test1-->test1</td>
      
      <td></td>
      
      <td><b>test1</b></td>
      <td><!--test1-->test1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>test2</b></td>
      <td><!--test2-->test2</td>
      
      <td></td>
      
      <td><b>test2</b></td>
      <td><!--test2-->+</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>test3</b></td>
      <td><!--test3-->test3</td>
      
      <td></td>
      
      <td><b>test3</b></td>
      <td><!--test3-->test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>test4</b></td>
      <td><!--test4-->test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test</td>
      
      <td></td>
      
      <td><b>test4</b></td>
      <td><!--test4-->test test </td>
    </tr>        
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I understood everything & it was indeed what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

The right way to do it is to create 4 blocks (div), every block contains a title  and a table. Then give every block width of 50% so you'll have two blocks in a row, and a fixed height.

Plus, please notice that "id" must be unique. If you want to give the same design to more that one block - use "class".

I did it for you - and I deleted all the IDs.

```css
#container{
    width: 500px;
    margin: auto;
}

table {
    font-family:Arial;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 10px;
}

.singleBlock{
    width:50%;
    float: left;
    height:300px;
    display:inline;
}
.title {
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#e13737;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-family: 'Arial Black', Gadget, sans-serif;
    line-height: 50px;
    }


table.listitems2 {
  width:200px;
    margin: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!-- gene description -->
<div id="container">
    <div class="singleBlock">
        <div class="title">GENE - A</div>
        <table  class="listitems2">
          <tr>
              <td><b>test1</b></td>
              <td><!--test1-->test1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td><b>test2</b></td>
              <td><!--test2-->test2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td><b>test3</b></td>
              <td><!--test3-->test3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td><b>test4</b></td>
              <td><!--test4-->test test test test test test test test test test test test test test</td>
          </tr>
          </table>
    </div>
    
    
    
     <div class="singleBlock">
          <div  class="title" >GENE - B</div>
          <table  class="listitems2">
          <tr>
              <td><b>test1</b></td>
              <td><!--test1-->1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td><b>test2</b></td>
              <td><!--test2-->+</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td><b>test3</b></td>
              <td><!--test3-->test3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td><b>test4</b></td>
              <td><!--test4-->test test </td>
          </tr>
          </table>        
    </div>
    
    
      <div class="singleBlock">
          <div  class="title" >GENE - C</div>
          <table  class="listitems2">
          
          </table>        
    </div>
    
     <div class="singleBlock">
          <div  class="title" >GENE - D</div>
          <table  class="listitems2">
          
          </table>        
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: how can I use a fixed heigth? The html-pages will be generated automatically, so every time the GENE_A_TEXT and GENE_B_text will have different amount of information in it, so the height will always be different –

Comment: Can you use JQuery? then maybe you can get B's height and put it as A's height. Another solution is to use tables to arrange the blocks (every row will have 2 blocks) but it's a really really ugly solution for developers.

Comment: JQuery is not possible. And what about the idea of Jaunt (see above) is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it's "ugly" but possible. You just need to learn CSS better to know how to align them correctly. Create a table with two rows and three columns (the middle column is for the space) and use classes wherever you need, not IDs. Good luck!