# how to make 2 tables in python next to each other (xpath, lxml, htmlbuilder)

Tags: html, css

Hey Guys i want to parse 2 xmls and i want to create a HTML, where i can see the information of the xmls. My code is very nice but unfortunely it creates me the one column under the other column. But i want column2 by the side of column1. That is my code. It does what i want, but i want the two tables next to each other.

```
import time
import lxml.html.builder as html
from lxml import etree

xmlData=etree.parse("http://17.19.8.39:8095/this/ressources/p1")
nodeTable=html.BODY(html.TABLE)

nodeData=xmlData.getroot()

xmlData=etree.parse("http://17.19.8.39:8095/this/ressources/p1")
nodeTable3=html.BODY(html.TABLE)


nodeRow5 = html.TH("P1-PreLive")
nodeTable3.append(nodeRow5)

nodeRow2 = html.TH("User-Id")
nodeTable.append(nodeRow2)
nodeRow3 = html.TH("conditions")
nodeTable.append(nodeRow3)
nodeRow4 = html.TH("name")
nodeTable.append(nodeRow4)
for nodeVin in nodeData.xpath("./user[@condition = 'fresh']|./user[@ condition = 'dirty']"):  

    nodeRow = html.TR(html.TD(nodeVin.attrib['id'],style="background-color:##FF0000" ), html.TD(nodeVin.attrib['condition'], style = "background-color:##FF0000"), html.TD(nodeVin.attrib['name'], style = "background-color:##FF0000"))

    nodeTable.append(nodeRow)





xmlData=etree.parse("http://17.19.8.39:8095/this/ressources/p3")
nodeTable4=html.BODY(html.TABLE)


nodeRow5 = html.TH("P3-TuI")
nodeTable4.append(nodeRow5)

nodeTable2  = html.BODY(html.TABLE)
nodeData=xmlData.getroot()

nodeRow2 = html.TH("User-Id")
nodeTable2.append(nodeRow2)
nodeRow3 = html.TH("conditions")
nodeTable2.append(nodeRow3)
nodeRow4 = html.TH("name")
nodeTable2.append(nodeRow4)
for nodeVin in nodeData.xpath("./user[@condition = 'fresh']|./user[@ condition = 'dirty']"):  

    nodeRow = html.TR(html.TD(nodeVin.attrib['id'], style="background-color:#e5e5e5" ), html.TD(nodeVin.attrib['condition'], style = "background-color:##e5e5e5"), html.TD(nodeVin.attrib['name'], style = "background-color:##e5e5e5"))

    nodeTable2.append(nodeRow)

print etree.tostring(nodeTable)
with open("out5.html", "wb") as f:
    f.write(etree.tostring(nodeTable2))
    f.write(etree.tostring(nodeTable))
```

so please heeeeelp. actually it looks like that: https://www.google.de/search?q=html+tabellen+untereinander&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7waSLy_DYAhVEKVAKHVvWCdMQ_AUICigB&biw=1696&bih=808#imgrc=_XLuPvtPxS0sLM:

Comment: What do you mean "it creates me the one column under the other column" ?

Comment: i mean that i get the one table. And after the one table ends, the other table starts just under the other table, but i want them to be next to each other. thanks for your answer

Comment: Of course you have "one table starting after the other" - that's what you asked for in your code. Note that a table is not a column, so if you hope to get right answers you'll have to ask your question using the right terms so everyone can clearlrly understand it - we are not telepaths you know ? (well, I am not at least).  And I still dont understand what you mean by "I want them next to each other" - here again it's NOT a __clear__ description of the expected result.

Comment: ok thanks for your advice. Ok i want to create a table. And next to the other table i want my second table (so in this case my "nodetable2"), like in this link: https://www.google.de/search?q=html+tables+next+to+each+other&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwju49jBzPDYAhUHOxQKHQojAd8Q_AUICigB&biw=1696&bih=808#imgrc=6MN38gp5xdxRlM:                                                                                 so that is what i want. Is this now clear? Can you help me

Comment: And the solution in https://stackoverflow.com/q/30975886/2564301 does not work for you, because ... ?

Comment: This is a html/css problem, not a python / lxml / xpath one. Just find some "two tables side by side" html/css cookbook example and update your code to generate the appropriate markup & css.

Comment: because i use python and not css. look at my code. thats the problem

Comment: yea i know thats it not exactly and  xpath/python problem. but i dont know, where in my code i can fix this problem. and i dont know the right syntax, can you help me please

Comment: please help me with the syntax its so complicated. as you can see in python you have to write "html.td" not <td> , etc